# SQL Select aspnet_UsersInRoles - multiple roles

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-roles

Suppose I had a customer table and each customer can belong to several roles. I'm trying to populate an old gridview of customers but if a customer is a member of a role like "external" then I do not want that customer to appear...BUT that particular customer is also a member of a role called "editor" thus the customer is still included.

In other words, how can I, in SQL, say...if that customer is in that role, don't include him at all even if he is a member of other roles.

Comment: With a join or a nested query..

Comment: Yes thank you. I did end up using a SELECT DISTINCT with an INNER JOIN and a WHERE nested NOT IN. Needed to use the SQL builder to visualize it too.